# Solar Battery Charging Circuit

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I designed this circuit:

[image: Circuit Diagram for the Battery Charging circuit]

to charge my 12 V UPS battery from a 40 W, 18 V solar panel. I specifically included an LM317T adjustable voltage regulator to control the output voltage to about 13.4 V as recommended by the battery manufacturer for cyclic use.

[image]

But I was surprised with the results since I obtained a very low charging current of **2.8 mA** which means it takes several days to charge the battery.

[image: Output current]

From the solar I expected 40/18 **= ~2 A**
Though I understand the circuit draws current from the current division among other reasons, this low output current is a concern for me.

**Any suggestions to improve the output current to **about 1 A** or more will be highly appreciated. Thank you.**

Comment: Measure the voltage at various points in your circuit, especially all pins of the regulator. Indicate where you measure current and with which node you plan to charge the battery ? whats the circuit on the far right supposed to be?

Comment: What is the output from the panel? Panel shaded or no sun?

Comment: On a general note: passing over an amp at 5 V drop through a linear regulator would probably incinerate it without any heatsink

Comment: The output from the panel is also in range of mA (which is also a concern)

Comment: use 10A scale and measure Isc short cct. on PV and get more sun. if you cant get 2A, it's no good.  then record Voc open cct.  and then Zmpt= Voc/Isc is the optimum load with Zmpt=PWM switched inductor into Vbat

Comment: Is the solar panel fully illuminated, in bright sunlight and no shade whatsoever? Only then could you expect anywhere near the maximum output. Any shade (or, for example, indirect or artificial lighting) will drastically reduce the output. Is the output voltage correct?